# Android application restarts when USB device is plugged in

Tags: java, android

For anyone who can help me:
I am currently working with the open accessory framework for Android 3.1+ and my application runs when the usb device is plugged in automatically. However during the event that I unplug and replug the usb while the application is running, android will run a new instance of my application on top of the current one that is already open. How can I keep android from opening another copy of my application that is already currently running?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set android:launchMode="singleTask" attribute for your root activity. this will ask the OS to bring the root activity to foreground if it is running, instead of create a new instance.

see here :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I had this same problem and added the singleTask propertie but now I don't see any dialog asking me if I want to use that app to open accesories nor so I see that the accessory is being recognized :(

Comment: My app still restarts whenever I plug, even after placing singleTask on root activity

Comment: Ok the one instance remains, but I don't want it to switch activity :/